# TypeScript propertyof

Tags: typescript

I know TypeScript has a [`keyof` keyword which yields the type of permitted property names for a given type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html). Is there also something like a `propertyof` which will get me the values of the keys of a given type? Specifically, I am wondering if there is a shorter way of doing

```
type Propertyof<T> = T[keyof T]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you discovered is the way to get the property value types:

```
type Propertyof<T> = T[keyof T]
```

There is no reason to have more features in the language then necessary, `propertyof T` would not be shorter, in fact as jcalz points out it is actually 2 characters longer.

Comment: `propertyof T`: 12 characters.  `T[keyof T]`: 10 characters.   

Comment: @jcalz yup, it's longer :). Even if it would be shorter, `keyof` has so many other uses `propertyof` seems too specialized to actually add to the language especially since we already have the building blocks to define it